# How to add an arrayformula in Google Sheet AppScript?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Can anyone suggest how I can add the following formula to Cell L2:L1000?

```
=arrayformula(if(ISBLANK(A2),"",if(and(M2="PLANNING",N2="TEST ONE"),"N",if(and(ISBLANK(J2),G2+7>today()),"Y",if(K2>G2+7,"Y","N")))))
```

I already tried the following, but it returned with an error message:
Syntax error: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list line: 7 file: code.gs.gs

```js
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var cell = sheet.getRange("B5");
  cell.setFormula("=arrayformula(if(ISBLANK(A2),"",if(and(M2="PLANNING",N2="BUILD AHEAD"),"N",if(and(ISBLANK(J2),G2+7>today()),"Y",if(K2>G2+7,"Y","N")))))");
}
```

I am expecting to have the same arrayformula on every single cell from L2 to L1000.

Comment: What is the point of using an arrayformula when your formula does not work as an array?

Answer (score 0):

#### Modification points:

- I think that your current issue is due to that your formula is enclosed by the double quotes. In the case of your formula, I think that the single quota can be used.
- In order to put your formula to "L2:L1000" of the active sheet, it is required to modify your script.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var formula = '=arrayformula(if(ISBLANK(A2),"",if(and(M2="PLANNING",N2="BUILD AHEAD"),"N",if(and(ISBLANK(J2),G2+7>today()),"Y",if(K2>G2+7,"Y","N")))))'; // This is from your script.

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  sheet.getRange("L2:L1000").setFormula(formula);
}
```

#### Reference:

- [getRange(a1Notation)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation)